# Actualización de valores array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

me gustaría saber como puedo actualizar los valores del array cuando se hace clic en el botón 'listado'. Cuando se da de alta a una persona, si llamo al método Persona.listarPersonas(), sí me acutaliza el array, sin embargo, cuando hago clic en listado, esos nuevos valores no aparecen. Por aquí dejo el html con JavaScript. Antes tenía la clase persona en archivo.js aparte, pero lo he sacado para comprobar si era por eso, pero tampoco me actualiza los valores. También en el método Persona.listarPersona había probado a pasarle por parámetro el array de personas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="esp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <title>Personas</title>
    </head>

<script>
    class Persona {

constructor(nombre, apellidos, direccion, fechaNac, genero, codigoPostal) {
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellidos=apellidos;
    this.direccion=direccion;
    this.fechaNac=fechaNac;
    this.genero=genero;
    this.codigoPostal=codigoPostal;
}
get getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}
get getApellidos() {  
    return this.apellidos;
}
get getEdad(){
    var hoy = new Date();
    return hoy.getFullYear() - this.fechaNac.getFullYear();
}
get getfechaNac() {
    return this.fechaNac;
}
get getGenero() {
    return this.genero;
}
get getCodigoPostal() {
    return this.codigoPostal;
}
static listarPersonas( ) {
    console.log("Listando personas:", personas);
    var ventana = window.open("", "ventana1", "height=600, width=600 left=50, top=50");
    ventana.document.write("<html> <head> <title> </title> </head> <body>");
    if (personas.length === 0) {
        ventana.write('No existen personas en el array');
    } else {
        ventana.document.write("<h1>Listado Array de todas las personas</h1>");
        ventana.document.write("<table> <tr> <td>Nombre y apellidos</td> </tr>");

        for (var i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) {
            ventana.document.write("<tr> <td>" + personas[i].nombre + " " + personas[i].apellidos + "</td> </tr>");
        }
        ventana.document.write("<tr> <td><button type='button' onclick='window.close();'>Cerrar ventana</button></td> </tr>");
        ventana.document.write("</table> </body> </html>")
    }
}
    }
    
    var personas = [
        new Persona("Juan", "Jiménez", "Calle Rosas nº7", new Date(1995, 11, 25), "masculino", 28830),
        new Persona("Eva", "Lucas", "Calle Margaritas nº15", new Date(1998, 10, 23), "femenino", 28840),
        new Persona("Mario", "García", "Calle Bernabeu nº27", new Date(2003, 10, 13), "masculino", 28850),
        new Persona("Juana", "Rivas", "Calle dos hermanas nº3", new Date(1985, 8, 17), "femenino", 28844)`introducir el código aquí`
    ];

    function validarPersona() {
        var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var apellidos=document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
        var direccion=document.getElementById("dirección").value;
        var fechaNac = document.getElementById("fecha_nac").value;
        var genero=document.getElementById("genero").value;
        var codigoPostal=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
 
        if (
        nombre.trim() !== '' &&
        apellidos.trim() !== '' &&
        direccion.trim() !== '' &&
        fechaNac.trim() !== '' &&
        genero.trim() !== '' &&
        codigoPostal.trim() !== '' &&
        isNaN(nombre) &&
        isNaN(apellidos) &&
        isNaN(direccion) &&
        isNaN(fechaNac) &&
        isNaN(genero) &&
        !isNaN(codigoPostal)
        ) {
    if (confirm('¿Está seguro?')) {
        var personaCreada = new Persona(nombre, apellidos, direccion, new Date(fechaNac), genero, parseInt(codigoPostal));
        personas.push(personaCreada);
        alert('Persona agregada correctamente');
        Persona.listarPersonas(personas);
    }
}

                else {
                    alert('Valores no permitidos');
                }
            }
            </script>

<body>
    <h2 class="titulo">Gestión de personas</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <h3> Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre"> </h3>
            <h3> Apellidos: <input type="text" id="apellidos"></h3>
            <h3> Dirección: <input type="text" id="direccion"></h3>
            <h3> Fecha de nacimiento: <input type="text" id="fechaNac"></h3>
            <h3> Género: <input type="text" id="genero"> </h3>
            <h3> Código postal: <input type="text" id="codigo"> </h3>
            <div class="botones">
                <input class="alta" type="submit" id="alta" value="Alta" onclick="validarPersona();">
                <input class="baja" type="submit" id="baja" value="Baja">
                <input class="modificacion" type="submit" id="modificacion" value="Modificación">
                <input class="listado" type="button" id="listado" onclick="Persona.listarPersonas();" value="Listado">

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema puede estar radicando en como llamas al metodo y como se muestra la ventana.. No es muy util abrirla dentro del metodo listarPersonas que tienes ahi.

Seria util pasar el array personas como parámetro al método listarPersonas

De esta forma

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="esp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title>Personas</title>
</head>

<script>
    class Persona {
    
        
        static listarPersonas(personas) {
            console.log("Listando personas:", personas);
            var ventana = window.open("", "ventana1", "height=600, width=600 left=50, top=50");
            ventana.document.write("<html> <head> <title> </title> </head> <body>");
            
            if (personas.length === 0) {
                ventana.write('No existen personas en el array');
            } else {
                ventana.document.write("<h1>Listado Array de todas las personas</h1>");
                ventana.document.write("<table> <tr> <td>Nombre y apellidos</td> </tr>");

                for (var i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) {
                    ventana.document.write("<tr> <td>" + personas[i].nombre + " " + personas[i].apellidos + "</td> </tr>");
                }

                ventana.document.write("<tr> <td><button type='button' onclick='window.close();'>Cerrar ventana</button></td> </tr>");
                ventana.document.write("</table> </body> </html>");
            }
        }
    }

    var personas = [
        new Persona("Juan", "Jiménez", "Calle Rosas nº7", new Date(1995, 11, 25), "masculino", 28830),
        //(resto de las personas)
    ];

    function validarPersona() {


        if (confirm('¿Está seguro?')) {
            var personaCreada = new Persona(nombre, apellidos, direccion, new Date(fechaNac), genero, parseInt(codigoPostal));
            personas.push(personaCreada);
            alert('Persona agregada correctamente');
        } else {
            alert('Valores no permitidos');
        }
    }

    function mostrarListado() {
        Persona.listarPersonas(personas);
    }
</script>

<body>
  
    <input class="listado" type="button" id="listado" onclick="mostrarListado();" value="Listado">

</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!